# Spring boot: Static resource not found when using an executable jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My situation:
resource directories:

```
--resources
  -- static
    -- css
      -- a.css
      -- b.css
    -- js
      -- aa.js
      -- bb.js

  -- templates
    -- index.html
```

Some code of index.html:

```
<link href="css/a.css" rel="prefetch">
<link href="css/b.css" rel="prefetch">
<link href="js/aa.js" rel="prefetch">
<link href="js/bb.js" rel="prefetch">
```

In Eclipse IDE
When I start the application, index.html will be rendered properly and the js/css can be fetched.
When I pack in jar and start 'java -jar xxx.jar', the js/css cannot be found.

How come?

I tried some solutions but not work:

a. I add the below configuration in application.yml

```
spring:
  resources:
    static-locations: classpath:/static/
```

not works

b. Add this configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");

}
```

not works

c. Add in pom.xml

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/static/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath>
            </resource>
</resources>
```

not works.

I check that the static directory has been packed into the jar and the jar directory is like:

```
-- xxx.jar
  -- BOOT-INF
    -- static
      -- css
        -- a.css
        -- b.css
      -- js
        -- aa.js
        -- bb.js
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: I would expect that one needs an absolute path, not a relative one so `/css/a.css` etc. Remove your "solutions" a,b,c from your code as those are only making things worse.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the path is wrong.

instead of href="css/a.css" use href="/css/a.css"

/ at beginning of the path.